# C# arraylist plus arraylist

Tags: c#

Lets say we have 2 arraylist
1 arraylist Premijos has {0.2,0.3,0.1,0,4}
2 arraylist Indeliai has {15000, 14000, 13000, 12000}

It should be like this 15000*0.2+14000*0.3+13000*0.1+12000*0.4
my code

```
public double ImtiVidurkiKiekvienam()
    {
        double v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < premijos.Count; i++)
        {
            v += premijos[i] * ind[i];
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: So, what is your problem with this code?

Comment: error Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'

Comment: Do not use ArrayList, use `List<double>` and `List<int>`

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions to your problem.

The first one is to use [`Convert.ToDouble`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
for (int i = 0; i < premijos.Count; i++)
{
    v += Convert.ToDouble(premijos[i]) * Convert.ToDouble(ind[i]);
}
```

But remember that it can throw an exception.

The second one, as said in comments, is to use `List<double>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'`" because ArrayList holds objects. It doesn't know what is the actual type of them. So you need to convert them manually while multiplying. Assuming that `premijos` is an `ArrayList` of `float` and `ind` is an `ArrayList` of `int` you can change your loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < premijos.Count; i++)
{
    v += float.Parse(premijos[i].ToString()) * int.Parse(ind[i].ToString());
}
```

Here we are `float.Parse` and `int.Parse` parses the "object" to float and int respectively.
Of course `ArrayList`s are outdated now. Just use arrays (`float[]` or `int[]`)or a generic collection like `List<T>`
If you used `float[]` and `int[]` as your collections, your method could have been shortened using LINQ as follows:

```
public double ImtiVidurkiKiekvienam()
{
    return premijos.Select((num, i) => num * ind[i]).Sum();
}
```